# Click event doesn't get triggered

Tags: javascript, forms, no-framework

I want the user to select the entire input box when he clicks on it.

In my case the input box is:

```
      <label for="bla">My checkbox</label>
      <input type="input" id="bla" name="check" value="checked" />
```

To do this I wrote the following JS:

```
function SelectAll(bar){   
    bar.focus();
    bar.select();
    console.log(bar);
}    
window.onload=function()
{
   var bla=document.getElementById("bla");
   bla.addEventListener('click',SelectAll(bla),false);       
};
```

But all i get in the console is `<input type="input" value="checked" name="check" id="bla">`
 once and no matter how much I click I cannot get any more.

Comment: Do you want user to be selected your input when he come to your page

Comment: No, i want it to be selected when he clicks on it. And only then.

Comment: when your click on your input add attribute autofocus here is reference for how autofocus will add as a attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_autofocus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) callback reference should have no parameters.

`.addEventListener('click', SelectAll)`

By adding `(bla)`, it is actually being called as `SelectAll(bla)(element)`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Summing up my research i come to the following consclusions:

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) callback reference should have no parameters since it passes the event to the function.

As such the correct way to implement the `listener` is `.addEventListener('click', SelectAll, false)`.

Since the `event` is passed but you want to work with the actual `element` you will need to use `bar.target` to access it.

Answer (score -2):

Try This :

```
$( "#bla" ).click(function() {
     bla.addEventListener('click',SelectAll(bla),false);    
    });
function SelectAll(element){   
    element.focus();
    element.select();
    console.log(element);
}
```

Comment: That uses jQuery and I am actively trying to avoid any kind of framework.

Comment: This does not solve the issue, it makes it even worse. Aside from the fact that you are adding jQuery, all your code does is add a jQuery click binding which on-click adds the original click binding written in JavaScript, which still has the same issue as it had originally. In addition, every time you click, your jQuery binding executes, adding another click binding.